# When were the Black Acts passed in Scotland?

Tags: legal-history, scotland

In 'The Scottish Legal System' [1](http://www.rps.ac.uk/static/historicalintro6.html), the authors say that

> The first printing press was introduced into Scotland in 1507, but it was not until 1541 with the printing of the Black Acts that it was applied to legislation.

However, [the Records of the Parliaments of Scotland state](http://www.rps.ac.uk/static/historicalintro6.html) that the Black Acts were not passed until May 1584.

Which source is correct?

[1](http://www.rps.ac.uk/static/historicalintro6.html) White, Willock & MacQueen; fifth edition (2013); para 2.15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, both are correct. The RPS refers to two different things as Black Acts: laws printed with a printing press using a heavy typeface (hence, "black") in [1541](http://www.rps.ac.uk/static/statutes_index.html), and laws that established Parliament as supreme over the church (called "black" because they were bad for the church) in [1584](http://www.rps.ac.uk/static/historicalintro6.html).